# Alternatives to Primesense depth cameras?

Tags: sensors, kinect, computer-vision

I'm looking for low-cost depth cameras (less than 1000 USD) with a range of more than 3 meters.

Currently, I have found only SoftKinetic DS-311 that meets these requirements.

Here are some other low-cost cameras that I found, but they have a short range:

- pmd[vision] camboard nano
- SoftKinetic DS-325

and others with a long range but high cost

- Panasonic D-Imager
- pmd[vision] CamCube 3.0
- SwissRanger SR4500
- Odos Imaging Real.iZ-1K

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* lahjaton_j, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Thanks for the kind response, you are definitely right about this. Do you know other sites with a post voting system for the purpose?

Comment: I'm not sure of an alternative site.  Actually, I'd be surprised if one could exist for specialty equipment like what is used on robots because the customer base is so much smaller -- you may have only dozens of possible reviews for a robot camera instead of the thousands or millions of possible reviews for a consumer camera.

Comment: I moved the question to HW recommendations, which is in beta: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/570/new-low-cost-depth-sensors-for-robotics